# How does Twitter Search API rate limit work?

Tags: twitter, limit, rate

I am not clear about what the Twitter rate limit, "350 requests per hour per access token/user", means. How they are limiting the request? In 1 request how much data i can get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rate limits are based on request, not the amount of data (e.g. bytes) you receive. With that in mind, you can maximize requests by using the available parameters of the particular endpoint you're calling. I'll give you a couple examples to explain what I mean:

1. One way is to set count, if supported, to the highest available value. On statuses/home_timeline, you can max out count at 200. If you aren't using it now, you're getting the default of 20, which means that you would (theoretically) need to do 10 more queries the get the same amount of data. More queries mean you eat up rate limit.
2. Using statuses/home_timeline again, notice that you can page through data using since_id and max_id, as described in [Working with Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines). Essentially, you keep track of the tweets you already requested so you can save on requests by only getting the newest tweets.
3. Rate limits are in 15 minute windows, so you can pace your requests to minimize the chance of running out in any give time window.
4. Use a combination of [Streams](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis) and requests, which increases your rate limit.

There are more optimizations like this that help you save request limit, some more subtle than others. Looking at the rate limits per API, studying parameters, and thinking about how the API is used can help you minimize rate limit usage.

Comment: can i get timeline of an user without authenticating the user

Comment: There was a time when you could do certain queries without authentication. However, in the latest release of the Twitter API v1.1, all requests must be authenticated.

Comment: when an authorized user logged in our application ,rate limit is considered with respect to the access token of that user or with respect to the access token of registered application means, does rate limit work globally for every user.

Comment: @live_alone - With normal authorization, where you're presenting the tokens of a user, rate limit applies to the access token of the individual user. There is an exception though - if you're using Application Only authorization, where the tokens belong to the application, the rate limits do apply to your application.

Comment: -actually i am using tweepy for fetching the information from twitter, when i use registered access token of my app its work fine, but when i use oauth and logged in as different user ,so i get different access token, but when i use these tokens to fetch the information i got unauthenticated tokens error. help me so that i can lower the rate limit by using these new access token of logged in user. As rate limit applies to access token of individual user.

Comment: @live_alone You might want to start a new question so that someone more familiar with tweepy can help you. Tip: be sure to show some code demonstrating where you've tried to make it work, which increases the chance of you getting a better answer.