# Twitter API Rate Limit Per User or Per Request?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, rate-limiting

I just have a quick question on the Twitter API rate limit. In this [official GitHub example](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/653248e62ae9c579d0c12e82c1566352bef9bdf7/User-Lookup/get_users_with_bearer_token.py#L12),
it says that you can have up to 100 usernames per user lookup request in the Twitter API. In the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits), it says that you can have up to 900 user lookup requests per 15 minutes. So, does this mean that I can look up 100 * 900 = 90,000 users in 15 minutes, or does looking up 100 users at once count as 100 requests? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, one refers to V1, the other V2. [Here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits) is the rate limits for V2. My guess would be if you request 100 users, that is 100 requests, but I could be wrong. (What makes me lean towards this, is the fact that under "Tips to avoid being rate limited" does NOT mention requesting multiple users at once counts it as a single request).

Comment: Whoops! I accidentally linked to V1, but the rate limit is still 900 requests per 15 minutes in V2. Thanks for your answer, but I'll wait until someone is 100% sure because I don't want to try too many requests and get my developer account suspended :)

Comment: I get that. Just to be clear, I think that you are limited to 900 users per 15 minutes. Not 90 000

Comment: This is quite confusing. So people are saying that rate limits are based on requests, not how much data you receive per request (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014621/how-does-twitter-search-api-rate-limit-work/19019731#19019731), but others are saying the opposite. I just don't want to do anything prematurely.

Comment: Yeah, but that's 8 years ago. Well, your best bet is to experiment. Make a request, and include the headers that are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305547/how-rate-limit-works-in-twitter-in-search-api?rq=1) . It will tell you how many requests you have left.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your help!